# jQuery change event on a DIV

Tags: jquery

I'm triggering a change event using jQuery on a DIV. The thing is that I have a couple of inputs hidden inside that div. When the event is triggered, the listener for the event is capuring both the input change as the div change.

I've created a little jsFiddle to demonstrate better what I'm talking about

https://jsfiddle.net/8m3s087e/

```
<div id="teste">
    <input type="hidden" id="t" name="lala" value="" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Btn" />
</div>

$("#btn").on('click', function() {
    $("#teste").trigger('change');   
    $("#t").trigger('change');
});

$("#teste").on('change', function() {
    alert('oi');
});
```

Well, I'm no jQuery expert, but can I prevent that behavior? I mean, if I trigger the event for the DIV, only the listeners with the div as a selector should be the ones called.

Thanks,
Lucas

Comment: `change` event on a div? Why? Is it a `contentEditable`? It seems like you're using it as a custom event, so just rename it to something other than `change` and the event won't bubble. https://jsfiddle.net/c05yv1zm/

Comment: Jan, we have a couple of controls that we wanted to behave like input elements. Many times we have to add the change event to a selector, but we dont know if the selector is an input or one of our control. If we changed the event name, we would have to check what that selector was and add the corrent event to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the events bubble up - you have to capture the `change` event on the input, and stop it from propagating:

```
 $("#t").on('change', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8m3s087e/3/

Comment: Note: This will also stop the event from bubbling up to your `form` which you may or may not want.

Comment: Even though it might interrupt the bubbling up to my form, that does not impact the system, so we're sticking with this answer. We did note that it might have that side effect Jan. Thank you for your help.